# React: Spread the return of a function in one line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to spread the result of a function directly, instead of storing then spreading it? In other words, is there a way to reduce these 2 lines into one?

```
const toto = removePreviousCase();
setMap({
    ...toto,
    player: {
        y: selectedCase.y,
        x: selectedCase.x
    }
});
```

Comment: The “thing” immediately following the `...` can by any expression (a function call is an expression).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just spread the `removePreviousCase` call into the object that `setMap` gets called with:

```
setMap({
    ...removePreviousCase(),
    player: {
        y: selectedCase.y,
        x: selectedCase.x
    }
});
```

(That said, keep in mind that clean, readable code is often the more important thing to strive for - if separating it out onto different lines is more readable, don't be afraid to do so. Only code golf if code-golfing [is the objective](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/))

Another option is:

```
const {
    x,
    y
} = selectedCase;
setMap({
        ...removePreviousCase(),
        player: {
           x,
           y
        });
```